# STREAM keyword in pig script that runs in Amazon Mapreduce

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a pig script, that activates another python program.
I was able to do so in my own hadoop environment, but I always fail when I run my script in Amazon map reduce WS.

The log say:

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2090: Received Error while processing the reduce plan: '' failed with exit status: 127
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigMapReduce.java:347)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigMapReduce.java:288)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigMapReduce.java:260)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigMapReduce.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$Child.main(TaskTracker.java:2216)

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
All I need is to use the cache('s3://') option when defining the streaming command

Comment: Would you mind showing your working implementation?  I'm in the same boat - I can get a python UDF to run in local mode but it fails when I deploy it to my cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the script is sent along to the Elastic MapReduce job?

Comment: Not sure, but you could try specifying the path to the script as a full URL including s3:// and all that, like you would with a JAR. See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?introduction.html#UsingJarsWithPig